# Single Visual Studio Azure Project deploy multiple Cloud Service

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment

Somewhat new to Azure.  We have 3 different cloud service accounts (dev/qa/prod).  We have the same 1 web role and 2 worker roles we'd like to deploy to these cloud service accounts.  In Visual Studio (2013), I have currently one Azure Project with the 1 web role and 2 worker roles.  I have created 3 different ServiceConfigurations for each environment.  I can create a deployment package using the corresponding ServiceConfiguration. So far so good.

Now, it seems I can only have one ServiceDefintion.csdef file.  If I want different VM sizing for my envs (i.e. different ServiceDefinition.csdef file for each env), how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found various solutions/options:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2012/07/02/transform-windows-azure-service-model-files-during-packaging.aspx
- [Azure: Is there any way to deploy different instance sizes for test/production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170755/azure-is-there-any-way-to-deploy-different-instance-sizes-for-test-production)

However, I ultimately resolved the issue at our deployment server (Octopus).  I have a single definition file and 2 config files (local and cloud) - the defaults in VS.  For workstation debug the local serviceconfiguration is used. When I build and package I use the cloud serviceconfiguration as starting point.  Then in Octopus I transform / variable substitute both the servicedefintion and serviceconfiguration based on target deployment environment.

Comment: How did you modify the service Def file inside a cspkg in octopus deploy? Is there any online resource on this?