# How to have more multiple ServiceConfiguration files not just ".local" and ".cloud"?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

**Context**

I have an Azure project in my solution for my web service. I have 3 Visual Studio configurations, Debug, Release1 and Release2.  I would like to configure both Release1 and Release2 for cloud deployment but with slightly different configurations (for example Release1 is https, but Release2 is pure http.)

I know I can create multiple deployment profiles (.azurePubxml) but as far as I see even I could have 100s of them, I only can refer only 2 service configuration from them: Local or Cloud

```
 <AzureServiceConfiguration>Cloud</AzureServiceConfiguration>
```

**Question:**

How can I have 3 different service configurations (.cscfg) for my 3 VS configurartions and 3 deployment profiles?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170755/azure-is-there-any-way-to-deploy-different-instance-sizes-for-test-production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your question is about multiple configurations for your cloud service, yes it is possible.

Right click on the Cloud Service project and then select `Manage Configurations...`.

[image]

You can copy an existing configuration to create a new one (for example, I copied `Local` configuration to create a `Staging` configuration).

[image]

As a result of this, I now have 3 cloud configuration files in my cloud project:

[image]

and when I go an manually package the file, I see three configuration options:

[image]